# Unchecking radiobutton with javascript based on selected parent radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a group of radiobuttons. If you select "Dagelijks, wekelijks, maandelijks" the div with the pink background is invisble (display: none). Only when you select the radiobutton "Geen" the pink div shows.   [Image of radiobuttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTUcw.png).

I used the following JS to show the div with ID div-pauze:

```
<script>
    function show1(){document.getElementById('div-pauze').style.display ='none';}
    function show2(){document.getElementById('div-pauze').style.display = 'block';}
</script>
```

This is the HTML markup:

```
     <ul class="list-unstyled radio-horizontal">
          <li><input id="dagelijks-test" name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Dagelijks" onclick="show1();"><label for="dagelijks-test">Dagelijks</label></li>
          <li><input id="wekelijks-test" name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Wekelijks" onclick="show1();"><label for="wekelijks-test">Wekelijks</label></li>
          <li><input id="maandelijks-test" name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Maandelijks" onclick="show1();"><label for="maandelijks-test">Maandelijks</label></li>
          <li><input id="geen-test" name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Geen" onclick="show2();"><label for="geen-test">Geen</label></li>
     </ul>

     <div class="col-sm-12 div-pauze">
          <h4>Tijdelijk pauzeren</h4>
              <p>Weet u zeker dat u onze nieuwsbrief niet meer wilt ontvangen? U kan de nieuwsbrief ook tijdelijk pauzeren.</p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><input id="3-maanden" name="dbfield" type="radio" value="Dagelijks"><label for="3-maanden">Ik wil de nieuwsbrief pauzeren voor 3 maanden</label></li>
          <li><input id="6-maanden" name="dbfield" type="radio" value="Wekelijks" ><label for="6-maanden">Ik wil de nieuwsbrief pauzeren voor 6 maanden</label></li>
          <li><input id="uitschrijven" name="dbfield" type="radio" value="Geen"><label for="uitschrijven">Ik wil me nu definitief uitschrijven</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The problem is when I deselect "Geen" and select any other radiobutton, the value in the pink div is still selected while only the div changed to display none. When you deselect the "Geen" radiobutton, it should clear all of the values in that div.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that your HTML example is missing the `id="div-pauze"` attribute on the div, but I presume this is a typo in the question otherwise it wouldn't be working at all.

To fix the issue you describe you need to set the `checked` property of each radio button within `#div-pauze` to `false`. You can do this by selecting them all with `querySelectorAll()` and then looping through them.

It's also worth noting that there's a few improvements you can make to the code here. Firstly if you wrap the radio `input` elements in the `label` you can remove the `for` attribute to make the HTML shorter and more simple.

Secondly, *don't use inline event attributes*. Attach your event handlers unobtrusively using `addEventListener()`. Similarly, always use the `change` event instead of `click` on checkboxes, radios and select elements.

With all that said, try this:

```js
var pauze = document.querySelector('#div-pauze');

document.querySelectorAll('.close').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', function() {
  pauze.style.display = 'none';
  pauze.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => el.checked = false);
}))

document.querySelectorAll('.open').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', function() {
  pauze.style.display = 'block';
}));
```

```css
#div-pauze {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled radio-horizontal">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="close" name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Dagelijks" />
      Dagelijks
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="close"name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Wekelijks" />
      Wekelijks
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="close" name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Maandelijks" />
      Maandelijks
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="open" name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Geen" />
      Geen
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="div-pauze" class="col-sm-12 div-pauze">
  <h4>Tijdelijk pauzeren</h4>
  <p>Weet u zeker dat u onze nieuwsbrief niet meer wilt ontvangen? U kan de nieuwsbrief ook tijdelijk pauzeren.</p>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
      <label>
        <input id="3-maanden" name="dbfield" type="radio" value="Dagelijks">
        Ik wil de nieuwsbrief pauzeren voor 3 maanden
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input id="6-maanden" name="dbfield" type="radio" value="Wekelijks">
        Ik wil de nieuwsbrief pauzeren voor 6 maanden
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input id="uitschrijven" name="dbfield" type="radio" value="Geen">
        Ik wil me nu definitief uitschrijven
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you tagged the question with jQuery, here's a jQuery implementation of the above:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $pauze = $('#div-pauze');
  
  $('.close').on('change', function() {
    $pauze.hide().find('input').prop('checked', false);
  });
  
  $('.open').on('change', function() {
    $pauze.show();
  });
});
```

```css
#div-pauze {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled radio-horizontal">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="close" name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Dagelijks" />
      Dagelijks
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="close"name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Wekelijks" />
      Wekelijks
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="close" name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Maandelijks" />
      Maandelijks
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="open" name="dbfield55" type="radio" value="Geen" />
      Geen
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="div-pauze" class="col-sm-12 div-pauze">
  <h4>Tijdelijk pauzeren</h4>
  <p>Weet u zeker dat u onze nieuwsbrief niet meer wilt ontvangen? U kan de nieuwsbrief ook tijdelijk pauzeren.</p>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
      <label>
        <input id="3-maanden" name="dbfield" type="radio" value="Dagelijks">
        Ik wil de nieuwsbrief pauzeren voor 3 maanden
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input id="6-maanden" name="dbfield" type="radio" value="Wekelijks">
        Ik wil de nieuwsbrief pauzeren voor 6 maanden
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input id="uitschrijven" name="dbfield" type="radio" value="Geen">
        Ik wil me nu definitief uitschrijven
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Haha you changed the comment after I already read it.. Thanks for the explanation on why to use the change event. I've changed the JS and classes to the change event. Do you know why it is better to not use inline attributes?

I know it's also possible to wrap the label around the input, but because of the CSS I already had from another page that works this way I chose to use it like this. Might remake it later with more time :) 

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @rorym. I have another question. Actually when the radiobutton "Geen" is checked, I don't want a value for this group of radiobuttons. So I'm going to give this a seperate name="". So then it will be two groups of radiobuttons.Is it possible based on the same JS as above to uncheck "Dagelijks, Wekelijks and Maandelijks" by checking "Geen"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can set `checked` to `false` on those checkboxes, the same way the example above does for those in the div. It's much, much easier to just give them all the same `name`, though

Comment: Okay I'm stupid. Using smarty I can just give "Geen" the current value of our database no matter which one it is. Thanks though...